# how to keep links working on no click through div

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to figure out how to make the popup textbox not able to be clicked through but keep the links clickable. Between trial and error and extensive searching I just can't figure it out.

Here is the code I'm working with.

https://pastebin.com/LpYRaQmJ

Comment: Please put your code in the post itself, not a link to your (private) pastebin.

Comment: 1) you didn't provide the code you have HERE within your post, 2) the link you have appended claims "This is a private paste". Essentially there is no way in which we can see your markup/CSS rules.

Comment: it says "This is a private paste. If you created this paste, please login to view it."

Answer (score 1):

Due to your question which doesn't contain code I have to speculate, but you can use `pointer-events: none` on an element to allow clicking the element behind it.

Comment: My bad!! Should be fixed now. This is my first time so I was a little confused.